# Understanding Banach–Alaoglu theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Banach–Alaoglu theorem states that:

> The closed bounded subsets of $X^*$ is compact with respect to the weak-* topology.

Is closeness and boundedness in weak-* topology on $X^*$? or the norm topology on $X^*$

Comment: Compact isn't equivalent to closed and bounded in general.

Answer (score 2):

It is norm-closed and norm-bounded.  A usual formulation of Banach-Alaoglu states that the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is weak-* compact.

EDIT: this is incorrect.  The set must be weak* closed.

Comment: The usual formulation and the one here are equivalent. Aren't they?

Comment: Yes.  It is a straightforward exercise to prove.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, of course you are correct.  I had my implications reversed.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is Banach, then norm-boundedness and weak$^*$-boundedness are equivalent because of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem. However, norm-closed bounded sets needn't be weak$^*$-closed (and thus cannot be weak$^*$-compact). An example is the unit ball of $c_0$ considered as a subset of $\ell_\infty= \ell_1^*$.

---

EDIT. The usual statement is that the polar $U^\circ=\{\varphi^*\in X^*: |\varphi(x)|\le 1\}$ of any neighbourhood of $0$ of a Banach space (or any topological vector space) is weak$^*$-compact. Hence all weak$^*$-closed and equicontinuous subsetes of $X^*$ are weak$^*$-compact. The example of the unit ball of $c_0$ in $\ell_\infty$ shows that one cannot replace weak$^*$-closedness by norm-closedness.

Comment: This is different form the above response. Which one is meant in Banach-Alaoglu theorem?

Comment: The version which is true in the dual of any topological vector space states that equicontinuous weak*-closed sets are weak*-compact.

Comment: I don't think on Banach spaces "closed-ness" is with respect to weak-* topology.

Comment: But for norm-closed it is not true.

Comment: Why the downvote?